# Why not make it a level playing field? Downvotes of 125+ rep persons on 125- rep persons should not be recorded

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

So, downvotes of persons with <75 (or is it <125) reps are not recorded.

May I know Why of this yet another discriminatory rule?
Do less reps take away any fundamental rights of a person anywhere?

If so, why not make it a level playing field?

Let the site also "NOT" record the downvotes of a 125+ rep person on the questions of a 125- rep person.

Answer (score 13):

Cause people who have earned a privilege have shown some ability to understand how things work. People with lower rep have not yet. SE fundamentally runs as a meritocracy

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89317/discussion-on-answer-by-journeyman-geek-why-not-make-it-a-level-playing-field-d).